# Поддержание подключения с сервером

Tags: java, android, сокет, tcp

Доброго времени суток.

Суть проблемы: есть однопоточный сервер, с которым android общается через сокеты. (Больше, чем один поток сделать нельзя, ибо сервер - это ESP'шка, или же nodeMCU)

На него (раз в 250 м/с или быстрее) нужно присылать всякий "мусор" по типу "windows:0", чтобы он не "отваливался" от wifi.

В самом приложении есть 4 кнопки. (Вперёд, назад, влево, вправо)

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии клавиши - на сервер отправлялись данные "servo:160" (не важно, но главное - те данные, которые нужны), а затем опять же отправлялся мусор. При "отжатии" клавиши - отправлялись, опять же, нужные денные, а затем шёл мусор. Как это сделать?

Есть код, который отправляет по сокетам данные серверу:

```
class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String message_to_send = "";
    public myTask(String message) {
        this.message_to_send = message;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
            s = new Socket(ip_get.getText().toString(), 1000);
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                printWriter.write(message_to_send);
                printWriter.flush();
                printWriter.close();
        s.close();
    }catch (IOException e){

    }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Код кнопок:

```
 turn_left.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    Return_servo();
                    return true;
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                   Turn_Left();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        turn_right.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    Return_servo();
                    return true;
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Turn_Right();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        stop_car.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    return true;
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Stop_Car();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ride_car.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    Stop_Car();
                    return true;
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Ride_Car();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Методы, которые они вызывают, а так же метод отправки:

```
private void Ride_Car() {
    send_text(range_get.getText().toString());
}

private void Stop_Car(){
    send_text("0");

}

private void Turn_Left(){
    send_text("8");

}

private void Turn_Right() {
    send_text("9");
}

private void Return_servo(){
    send_text("7");
}
public void send_text(String message){
    myTask mt = new myTask(message);
    mt.execute();
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. 4-й день мучаюсь с этим....

Comment: Я конечно  не особо в теме, но насколько помню сам сокет поддерживает соединение, пока открыт, без всякого мусора. То есть по идее Вам нужно открыть один сокет на всю сессию и слать все пакеты через него. А не открывать/закрывать новый на каждый пакет данных.

Comment: @woesss, там суть в том, что если ничего долго не слать на сервер (ESP) - начинаются задержки, правда, они небольшие (где-то 200 м/c), но при управлении машиной - очень сильно ощутимо. (Нажал кнопку, а она уже врезалась, к примеру). Если же после длительного перерыва быстро понажимать вправо-влево - тогда все начинает работать без задержек..